# Programmatically create hiddenfor fields for model properties not explicitly used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So this is a bit of a 'how can I be lazier?' or 'can I be super overprotective?' type of question.  The scenario I'm trying to account for is this...

A model is updated with a new field, but for whatever reason the addition of the property in the model's update user interface is forgotten while the explicit setting of it is implemented in the db access controller.  When the user clicks submit, the value of this property makes it to the controller as 'null' and summarily the database value is 'updated' to null.

Is there a way to get the properties on the model that are not explicitly put into the form, and add hiddenfors for these properties? (Worst case scenario, this value is not updated as opposed to losing data).

Edit: Potential Scenario

Initial object (used as the model on the form)

```
public MyObject 
{
   public string Value1 { get; set; }
   public string Value2 { get; set; }
}
```

The form has

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Value1)
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Value2)
```

Later, someone comes along and adds

```
public string Value3 { get; set; }
```

to the MyObject, but forgets to add a

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Value3)
```

This results in Value3 being submitted as null when the form is submitted. What I'm trying to figure out is if it is possible to add something to the form similar to the following:

```
foreach (var nonExplicitlyUsedProperty in Model.Properties) 
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.nonExplicitlyUsedProperty)
}
```

In the above scenario, this would be the equivalent of adding

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Value3)
```

at the bottom of the form.

Comment: hidden fields can be created to store values.. have you googled how to use hiddenfields...?

Comment: Yes, I'm wanting to loop through all of the properties on the model that haven't been explicitly used in the form and create a hiddenfor for each one.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options:

- Client-Side Validation
- Server-Side Validation
- Server-Side Sanitize

It sounds like your utilizing a *Form Action* which will automatically submit data to your *Controller*.  You'll either need to validate the data from the Client before it is passed to the server.

Another approach would be to simply validate the parameter, to avoid a *Null* being passed or modify your *SQL* to ignore a *Null* value passed to it before it does the update.

The other approach would be to couple the functionality of the UI in a manner that is better represented for your *Model* and *Controller*.  This way it is far more fluid and easy to understand.

---

*Important:*
You can use a *Hidden Field* to store data in when the model is initialized, but your introducing extra data and need to cater / regulate before you can proceed.  Though the hack may solve your problem, it isn't ideal truly as it bypasses your problem rather then truly solving it.

---

```
@if(Model != null)
{
     foreach(var content in Model)
     {
         <div>
              <input type="hidden" id="hdName" name="name" value="@content.Name" />
         <div>
     }
}
```

By using this hidden field, you'll then have to ensure when the user does change the field, the hidden field is updated like so:

```
$('#txtName').blur(function () {
     $('#hdName').val($(this).val());
});
```

As you can see how using *Hidden Fields* can truly become a nightmare, so I suggest you rethink your solution.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the final answer for what I have been trying to do...

First build out the form (as normal).

Then generate hidden input fields for all of the properties on the model like so... using string format to give it slightly different name/id attributes from the explicitly defined input fields' name/id. (Since ASP.Net passes values from view to controller by name instead of by id, but jQuery standard seems to be to use ids instead of name, account for both situations)

```
@foreach (var property in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    <input type="hidden" name="@(String.Format("{0}_2", property.Name))" id="@(String.Format("{0}_2", property.Name))" value="@property.GetValue(Model, null)" />
}
```

Afterwards, use jQuery to iterate through the hidden inputs, remove the discriminator that was added to the "name" property to get the actual property name, then check if the input with id of that value (the original property name) has a value.  If it DOES have a value, the hidden input is not needed and can be removed, otherwise, rename the hidden input name attribute (since that's how ASP.Net passes the value to the controller) to the original property name.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
            var actualPropertyName = $(this).attr("id").substr(0, ($(this).attr("id").length - 2));
            var value = $("#" + actualPropertyName).val();
            if (value != null) {
                $(this).remove();
            } else {
                $(this).attr("name", actualPropertyName);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```