# Return to Controller complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a parent model which looks like the following:

```
public class ConflictModel
{
    public ConflictModel()
    {
        ...
    }
    public GeneralViewModel BaseTable { get; set; }
    public GeneralViewModel Table1{ get; set; }
    public GeneralViewModel Table2 { get; set; }
    public List<dynamic> DistinctRows { get; set; }
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}
```

GeneralViewModel is the following:

```
public class GeneralViewModel
{
    public List<RowTypeModel> RowType {get; set;}
    public List<RowTypeChangesModel> RowTypeChanges { get; set; }
}
```

`RowTypeModel` and `RowTypeChangesModel` just contain properties, fields and constructors so I won't include it here for the sake of brevity.

I'm able to populate the `Values` field within `ConflictModel` using this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ConflictResolved", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Values, new SelectList(selectList))
}
```

My issue is that I'm trying to return `Table1` and `Table2` aswell so I can use it I've tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792932) and I've placed it within the using statement but I'm still getting null values for it. As I don't know which model from within `GeneralViewModel` that I'll be getting in the PartialView I've chosen to try to get the value explicitly. Later on down the line they'll be other values added to `GeneralViewModel`. I had gotten the javascript and the `<input>` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28197549/10169277)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[type='hidden']").each(function() {
            var actualPropertyName = $(this).attr("id").substr(0, ($(this).attr("id").length - 2));
            var value = $("#" + actualPropertyName).val();
            if (value != null) {
                $(this).remove();
            } else {
                $(this).attr("name", actualPropertyName);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

@model Models.GeneralViewModel

@{
    var gvmProps = @Model.GetType().GetProperties();
    
}

@foreach (var gvmProp in gvmProps)
{
    var item = (System.Collections.IList)gvmProp.GetValue(@Model);
    if (item != null && item.Count > 0)
    {
        //This is the List<model> which has been populated so find the properties and put in the hidden tag
        var props = item[0].GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(item[i]) != null)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="@(String.Format("{0}_2", prop.Name))" id="@(String.Format("{0}_2", prop.Name))" value="@prop.GetValue(item[i], null)" />
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote:  **_`RowTypeModel` and `RowTypeChangesModel` just contain fields and constructors_**. Check that you are using properties but not fields. The binding doesn't work on fields.

Comment: My bad meant to say properties

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the table1 and table2 properties within your form the naturally empty data will be returned on post call. So add hidden fields within the form and map the properties of your table1 and table2.

Comment: There is part of Table1 and Table2 which is used for filling in the dropdown menu within the form. I probably wasn’t clear before but I’ve been trying to add in the hidden fields by using a partial page that accepts GeneralViewModel and will display all properties for it. The partial page is within the form and the code for it can be seen in the last code block.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort it out. Because of the way the parent model is my name/id fields in the input tag were incorrect so it couldn't bind them together. The name/id tag should have looked like this:

`Table1.RowType[0].Property1`
Where 0 is the index within the list and keeps changing. Property1 can be any of the properties within the model.

The Partial page should have been as follows:

```
@model Models.Conflict_Model

@{
    var gvmProps = @Model.Conflicts.GetType().GetProperties();
    var conflictProps = @Model.GetType().GetProperties();
}
    
    
@foreach (var conflictProp in conflictProps)
{
    if (conflictProp.Name == "Table1" || conflictProp.Name == "Table2")
    {
        var gvmItem = conflictProp.GetValue(@Model);
        foreach (var gvmProp in gvmProps)
        {
            var item = (System.Collections.IList)gvmProp.GetValue(gvmItem);
            if (item != null && item.Count > 0)
            {
                var props = item[0].GetType().GetProperties();
                for (int i = 0; i < item.Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (var prop in props)
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" name="@(String.Format("{0}.{1}[{2}].{3}", conflictProp.Name, gvmProp.Name, i, prop.Name))" id="@(String.Format("{0}.{1}[{2}].{3}", conflictProp.Name, gvmProp.Name, i, prop.Name))" value="@prop.GetValue(item[i], null)" />
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```